# Controller level path variable exceptions

Tags: spring-mvc

Consider the following hypothetical controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="index/{user_id}")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="post/{post_id}")
    public String getPostById(@PathVariable final int post_id){
        if(post_id==0){
             throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
         }
       return "home";
    }
}
```

ResourceNotFoundException is mapped to HTTP 404 error:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    public ResourceNotFoundException(){
        super();
    }
}
```

If anyone tries to access a url say `index/1/post/0`,then the handler method would throw a 404 error,and I can accordingly show a error page with the message 'Resource Not found'.
But imagine a scenario in which the user tries to access a url of the form `index/12/post/1` , and I query the db for user with user id 12 ,which does not exist. In that case,I want the Spring to generate a 404 error,the same way as I did with handler method. Is such a thing possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here .
There is a workaround to this problem .

One can create an Interceptor ,extract path variables in that interceptor, and check for resource validity there.If the resource is not found , throw some exception , and catch it using an aspect ( @ControllerAdvice ).
Here's the gist : https://gist.github.com/ankushs92/0e97e070401a1bb5fe55